# Network connection was lost Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, binary, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload an update to one of my apps but i just keep getting the error on Xcode 7.3.1 which was updated yesterday. 
Is there any alternative ways that i can upload binary to iTunes connect? I tried Application loader but it also requires to log into your account on Xcode first.

[image]

UPDATE:

Seems like Apple's server was down for a while. Now it is working.

Comment: I'm having the same error. It seems there is a problem on Apple's side.

Comment: It's resolved just now! I'm able to start to upload a build finally.